# initializer_list and default constructor overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Y {};

struct X
{
    X(initializer_list<Y>) { cout << "yay" << endl; }
    explicit X() { cout << "boo" << endl; }
};

X f()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out "boo".  Why doesn't it print out "yay" ?

Is there anyway to differentiate the following two constructions:

1. `X()`
2. `X{}`

or

1. `return X();`
2. `return {};`

or

```
void g(const X&)
```

1. `g(X())`
2. `g({})`

Thanks.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `explicit` with a default ctor, it is only used for ctors that may be called with exactly one argument, to forbid implicit type conversion.  For example, `MyObject x = 9;` is only possible if `MyObject` has a non-`explicit` ctor `MyObject(int)`.  In your example, `explicit` is simply ignored by the compiler.

Comment: yes, I thought (incorrectly) that it might help make this overload go the way I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anyway to differentiate the following two constructions:

No. They are not different constructs.

The primary purpose of the {} constructor syntax was to introduce *uniform* initialization, to have initialization work the same everywhere. If there was a difference between them, it wouldn't be uniform.

If you want to use the empty initializer list constructor, you have to state that you're passing an initializer list explicitly. Like this: `return initializer_list<Y>{};` Of course, one of the other purposes of uniform initialization is to not have to type out typenames so much, so you can achieve the same effect with `return {{}};`

Comment: Your direct answer is technically correct (ie No).  Note however Mike Seymour's answer "{{}}" and "X({})".

Answer (score 5):

`return {};` will always use a default constructor if there is one.

`return X({});` or `return {{}};` will construct from an empty initialiser list.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the default constructor because list initialization with `{}` is meant to be a short form of value initialization always, disregarding of other constructors, even if they are initializer list constructors.

> Is there anyway to differentiate the following two constructions: ...

The `X()` is always value initialization, while `X{}` is only value initialization if `X` has a default constructor. If it is an aggregate, then `X{}` is aggregate initialization (initializing the members of `X` by a `{}` recursively). If it only has initializer list constructors and no default constructors, then `X()` is invalid and `X{}` could be valid

```
struct A { A(initializer_list<int>); };
A a = A{}; // valid
A b = A(); // invalid
```

Essentially, what `X{}` does depends on what `X` is. But `X()` always value initializes.

> ... or return X(); vs return {};

Something subtle to mention... In `return {}` the target is copy-list-initialized, while in `return X();` first direct-initializes an `X`. But even though it is copy-list-initialized, it *can* use an `explicit` default constructor, because value initialization doesn't care about `explicit`. However when you do `return {}` and you try to use an explicit non-default constructor you will error out

```
struct A {
  explicit A(initializer_list<int>);
};

A f() { return {}; } // error!

struct B { 
  explicit B();
};

B g() { return {}; } // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be a bit more explicit:

```
return initializer_list<Y>();
```