# C++ direct list initialization with deleted default constructor

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following class definition. I included a private `x` to make sure it is not an aggregate.

```
class A {
 private:
  int x;

 public:
  A() = delete;
  A(std::initializer_list<int>) { printf("init\n"); }
};
```

Now if I initialize this object with `A a = A{}`, it will say `A::A()` is deleted. I guess it is trying to call `A::A()` but it is deleted. If I comment out that line, so `A::A()` is automatically generated. Then if I run this code, I could see that it is calling `A::A(std::initializer_list<int>)`!

And more confusing, if I define `A() = default`, the initialization calls `A::A()` again.

Can anyone point me to the right direction of understading this behavior? Thanks!

I'm using G++ 6.3.0 with flag `-std=c++17`.

Comment: It chose the correct constructor each time.

Comment: Then what is the "correct" constructor in this case? @paddy

Comment: The problem I'm having is, depending on whether `A::A()` is implicit or defaulted or deleted, it exhibits different resolution. @paddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is correct.

First of all:

```
// Calling
A a = A{}; // equals A a = A();,
```

which was a convenience uniformization of the list-initialization idiom.
Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9020606/3754223

### Case A:

```
class A {
     private:
         int x;

     public:
         **A() = delete;**
         A(std::initializer_list<int>) { printf("init\n"); }
};
```

As said above, A a = A{} will be ... = A(), which is deleted.

### Case B:

```
class A {
     private:
         int x;

     public:
         A(std::initializer_list<int>) { printf("init\n"); }
};
```

In this case, there's no default constructor provided, since you have your initializer-list constructor be defined. Consequently {} is converted to an empty initializer list implicitely!

### Case C:

```
class A {
     private:
         int x;

     public:
         **A() = default;**
         A(std::initializer_list<int>) { printf("init\n"); }
};
```

In this case the empty default constructor is available and A{} is converted back to A(), causing it to be called.

Please refer to the below pages and get a thorough read into it. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

### Finally:

Using:

```
A a = {{}};
```

Would cause that ALWAYS the initializer-list constructor is called, as the outer-curly-brackets denoted the init-list, and the inner a zero-constructed element. -> Non-empty initializer-list... (See stackoverflow link above again!)

And btw, I cannot understand why the question is downvoted, considering that this is a really tricky part...

Comment: I read value initialization on cppreference before I came here with the question. But thanks to your explanation I have a new understanding. On cppreference, it says "If T is a class type that has no default constructor...". So I guess, an implicit default constructor satisfies the case that T has no default constructor. Is that what it meant?

Comment: I guess ppl downvote just because the question is too tricky for them to notice at a first glance. :(

Comment: @Hot.PxL "If T is a class type that has no default constructor but has a constructor taking std::initializer_list, list-initialization is performed." -> list-initialization. BUT: "if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;", see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988297/deleted-default-constructor-objects-can-still-be-created-sometimes

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of cases listed, so let us go over them one by one.

```
A() = delete;
A(std::initializer_list<int>) { ... }
```

Writing `A a = A{};` will indeed try to call the deleted default constructor, and your code fails to compile.

What you have above is [list initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#1), and because the [*braced-init-list* is empty](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.4), [value initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.1) will be performed. This selects the deleted default constructor, which makes your code ill-formed.

---

> If I comment out that line, so `A::A()` is automatically generated

No, this is not the case. There is no implicitly declared default constructor due to the presence of the user provided constructor that takes an `initializer_list`. Now, `A a = A{};` will call the `initializer_list` constructor, and in this case the `initializer_list` will be empty.

---

> if I define `A() = default`, the initialization calls `A::A()` again

This behaves the same as the first case, except the default constructor is explicitly `default`ed instead of `delete`d, so your code compiles.

---

Finally,

> I included a private `x` to make sure it is not an aggregate

There's no need for this, defining a constructor makes `A` a non-[aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178175/241631).

Comment: Oh! You are right that there is "no implicitly declared default constructor" if I defined any constructor. My C++ knowledge must have gotten rusty :(

Answer (score 1):

List initialization follows a very specific ordering, as laid out in [[dcl.init.list]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3). The two relevant bullet points and their relative ordering are highlighted:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>   — If `T` is an aggregate class and [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a character array and [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is an aggregate, [...]
>   — **Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.**
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std::initializer_list<E>`, [...]
>   — **Otherwise, if `T` is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7).**
>   — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, [...]
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is an enumeration with a fixed underlying type (7.2), [...]
>   — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.
>   — Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

An empty initializer list for class types with default constructors is a special case that precedes normal constructor resolution. Your class isn't an aggregate (since it has a user-provided constructor), so `A{}` will attempt to value-initialize `A` if `A` has a default constructor. It doesn't matter if that default constructor is *accessible*, it only matters if it *exists*. If it exists and is inaccessible (your first case), that's ill-formed. If it exists and is accessible (your third case), then it's invoked. Only if your class does not have a default constructor will the constructors be enumerated, in which case the `A(initializer_list<int> )` constructor will be invoked with an empty initializer list (your second case).