# why is list initialization not invoked when initialize this class?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, list-initialization, value-initialization

according to value initialization described in this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

> If T is a class type that has no default constructor but has a constructor taking std::initializer_list, list-initialization is performed.

so I was expecting when initialize the class in bellow code snippet will invoke `Myclass(const std::initializer_list<int> &l)` , but the compiler says

```
> the default constructor of "Myclass" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

why is that?  this is the code, I compiled with Mingw64 C++11 on windows.

```
#include <iostream>
class Myclass {
    public:
     Myclass() = delete;
     Myclass(Myclass &&m) {}
     Myclass(const Myclass &m) {}
     Myclass(const std::initializer_list<int> &l) { std::cout << "initializer list"; }
};
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Myclass m2 {};
     Myclass m1={};
}
```

Comment: "If `T` is a class type that has no default constructor..." But `T` does have a default constructor, which is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Myclass` does have a default constructor; which is just marked as `delete` explicitly. So the effect of value-initialization should be:

> 1. if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization);

In [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) the deleted default constructor is selected and the program is ill-formed.

If not to declare the default constructor as

```
class Myclass {
    public:
     // Myclass() = delete;
     Myclass(Myclass &&m) {}
     Myclass(const Myclass &m) {}
     Myclass(const std::initializer_list<int> &l) { std::cout << "initializer list"; }
};
```

Then `Myclass` doesn't have default constructor; (and no [implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor) because of other user-declared constructors). Then [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is performed (as you expected), as the effect

> All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) against a single argument of type `std::initializer_list`

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663166/c-direct-list-initialization-with-deleted-default-constructor/42663598). in a nutshell:

- If the default constructor is explicitly deleted, the compiler will assume there can't be any default constructor
- If, however, you remove the `Myclass() = delete;` line, it will choose the best constructor, aka your `initialized_list` one.